# No longer receiving iAd revenue or requests?

Tags: app-store-connect, iad

I have a few applications on the App Store that have iAd banners. One of my applications no longer displays iAd banners anymore. I have not updated the application or anything. Fill rate, requests etc. are all displaying 0. I do have the *Live Ads* status for the application.

Any ideas as to why this is happening and how I could solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are these applications older applications? I read somewhere recently, going to try to find it, that applications that use static launch images, only support a few older screen dimensions (iPhone3/4/5), and are required to be stretched to meet the newer screen dimensions (iPhone6/6+) will not receive iAd banners. Implementing Auto Layout, and using a `LaunchScreen.storyboard` in your application should fix these issues.

I have not tested this extensively but all of my older applications that fit the example I've given have stopped receiving iAd banners. My newer applications that implement Auto Layout, use a `LaunchScreen.storyboard`, and are universal receive iAd banner advertisements just fine.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that out